# Using CORS to restrict who can send a post request

Tags: angularjs, security, cors

I'm currently trying to configure a route we can call it `sub.domain.com/route` and on `domain.com` I have a angular app that sends a post to that end point.

What I'm trying to figure out is do I have to add in CORS to `sub.domain.com/route` to only allow post requests from `domain.com`?  Or do I have to create a tokening system on `domain.com`to prevent someone from being able to send curl requests and use that route or to use that route on their website/app without my consent?

I'm trying to limit people who can access that route to only people who are physically on `domain.com` using my application and clicking the button that sends the post request.

Comment: You'll need to use some other form of authentication (e.g., tokening, password, etc...) as CORS will only affect whether or not resources such as scripts, served to a user's browser from one domain will be able to interact with services hosted on another.  This will do nothing to help against CURL requests, proxies, etc...

Comment: @10BitDev thank you this answers my question.  If you want to write it as a answer I will accept it.

Comment: You're welcome nadermx.  Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use some other form of authentication (e.g., tokening, password, etc...) as CORS will only affect whether or not resources such as scripts, served to a user's browser from one domain will be able to interact with services hosted on another. This will do nothing to help against CURL requests, proxies, etc...